# In Perl, how can I match one string against a list of other strings?

Tags: perl, string-matching

I want to check an element in an array, `$columns[2]`, against a small list of strings. The way I have it now is;

```
if (   $columns[2] eq 'string1' 
    || $columns[2] eq 'string2' 
    || $columns[2] eq 'string3' 
    || ...) { 
   ...
}
```

It seems there must be a better way than all the OR's.

Comment: `if (grep {$_ eq $columns[2]} qw (string1 string2 string3)) {} `

Comment: If the string's are similar looking, you may explore a regex that represents a match of those strings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/search.html?q=grep) is for:

```
my $element_exists = 
   grep { $columns[2] eq $_ } qw(string1 string2 ... stringN);
```

An alternative would be to use [`first`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#first), which will stop processing once it finds a match. This way if you first string matches `$columns[2]` you don't have to compare the remaining n-1 strings:

```
use List::Util qw/first/;

my $element_exists = 
   defined first { $columns[2] eq $_ } qw(string1 string2 ... stringN);
```

You could also you [`any`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#any) (as @ThisSuitIsBlackNot suggests below) for this purpose, the slight difference being that first returns the value of the element that matches the condition, any returns a boolean:

```
use List::Util qw/any/;

my $element_exists = 
   any { $columns[2] eq $_ } qw(string1 string2 ... stringN);
```

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Nope, `any` makes more sense.

Comment: Yeah, if you use `first` you should probably check that `$element_exists` is defined in case it matched a falsey value; `any` always returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex.

```
if( $columns[2] =~ /^$string1|$string2|$string3$/ )
```

Make sure to use the `^` and `$` to make sure that `$string1`, `$string2` or `$string3` is not just contained in `$columns[2]`.

Comment: That should be:"if( $columns[2] =~ /^($string1|$string2|$string3)$/"

Otherwise it will match string2 as a substring